# How can I make a mini English-Chinese dictionary for Ubuntu?

Tags: terminology

When you open your Ubuntu, many English words are used. For example, *accessories*, *education*, *graphics*, *internet*, *office*, *other*, *sound*, *video*, *system tools*, *preferences*, *run*, and *log out* will all appear in the GUI.

How can I get a list of all English words used in the Ubuntu GUI?

I want a list of all English words so I can translate them into Chinese, to create a glossary for Ubuntu: a guide in Chinese to English-language Ubuntu  terminology. This would work as a mini dictionary: a two-columns file with English on the left and Chinese on the right.

It is a joke to write the whole thing just from looking at the words on the GUI. I want a smart way to do the task. Is there a list of all the words used by Ubuntu?

[image: Screenshot of text editor showing English and Chinese words]

Typing by hand as I come across words in the GUI is a foolish way to get the task done.

1. Copy out all English words one-by-one from the GUI when the locale is set to `en_us`.
2. Copy out all Chinese words one-by-one from the GUI when the locale is set to `zh`.
3. Put them together in one file, with English on the left and Chinese on the right.

Is there a smarter way to do this?
Which character in my /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive  ?

Comment: I don't think there is a list somewhere. However, if there is a list, there will also be a list with the corresponding Chinese translation, as Ubuntu is fully translated into Chinese.

Comment: Don't know if you already knew, but there is already a chinese [version](http://www.ubuntu.com/desktop/ubuntu-kylin) of Ubuntu

Comment: I knew there is a chinese version,there is chinese dictionay,there is a english dictionay,so there is no need for an english-chinese dictionary?

Comment: NO,absolutely not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are many ways which are used to store internationalized strings depending on the GUI toolkits or specifications.

- The ones shown in the screenshot are from menu `.directory` files. Use same standard as `.desktop` from freedesktop project. See [Desktop Entry Specification: Localized values for keys](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/ar01s04.html)

  Here a script to extract them

  1. Create a shell file

     ```
     nano extract_zh_translation.sh
     ```

     Add

     ```
     #!/bin/bash            

     for f in $(ls $1)
     do
             name_en=`sed -n -e '0,/Name/{s/^\s*Name\s*=\s*//p}' $f`
             name_zh=`sed -n -e '0,/Name\[zh_CN\]/{s/^\s*Name\[zh_CN\]\s*=\s*//p}' $f`

             case `echo ${#name_en}/8 | bc` in
             3|2)    echo -e $name_en'\t'$name_zh
                     ;;
             1)      echo -e $name_en'\t\t'$name_zh
                     ;;
             0)      echo -e $name_en'\t\t\t'$name_zh
                     ;;
             esac
     done
     ```
  2. Make it executable

     ```
     chmod +x extract_zh_translation.sh
     ```
  3. Run it on menu directory entries

     ```
     ./extract_zh_translation.sh "/usr/share/desktop-directories/*.directory"
     ```

     Here is [an output sample](http://paste.ubuntu.com/12458719/)
  4. If you want application menu entries too

     ```
     ./extract_zh_translation.sh "/usr/share/applications/*.desktop"
     ```

     Here is [an output sample](http://paste.ubuntu.com/12458822/)
- Other translations of Unity GUI is using `gettext`.

  Files having the `.gmo` or `.mo` extension, are the final binary format. Check:

  ```
  locate -br .mo$ | grep zh_CN
  ```

  The source files have `.po` extension, you can download them from https://translations.launchpad.net/ or by downloading the complete source, example:

  ```
  apt-get source unity
  ```
- Other GUI toolkits like Qt & Java are using different formats.

Answer (score 5):

Search for Ubuntu Translations https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Translations/

You can get the Expressions and Translations there.

Comment: I want to make a mini dictionay : a english-chinese ubuntu glossary,on the left is english ,on the right is chinese, tow columns on the file,it is a joke to write every words looking at the words on the gui ,i want a smart way to do that task.

Comment: If you register with lanchpad as a tranlator you get acces to the online traslation afaik. There you can copy the english and the translated words. As i am not a translator i cannot cive you the exact information you look for only this hint to look for ubuntu translations which have the lists you are searching for.

Comment: This is the only answer at time of writing that seems to be on the right track. Why re-invent the wheel? Get the .mo files for the two languages you want to look at and presto! I suggest an editor like Meld for a 3-way merge to get what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I think he is referring to another problem. On my Ubuntu I have setup English, Hebrew and French. You have to go to System Settings, Language Support and add the additional languages.

To have it boot up in a different language, you drag the preferred language to the top of the list. For me, it works like a charm.

Comment: no ,not to set locale as chinese ,i just want to make a english-chinese ubuntu terminology to help people to  learn both operating system and english language at the same time.

Comment: I think it is a cool idea.

Comment: So you want the menu to appear in 2 languages? Don't know how to do that but I use Google translate and it does a rather good job.

Comment: He just wants to create a dictionary of terms for Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Start it up in a VM, take screenshots, run a OCR tool on the pictures.
This is only a little better than doing it by hand.
It would be great if you could just pipe the text into a file, but the os that would do that isnt awake yet.

Answer (score -1):

A chinese version of Ubuntu is available and supported: [Ubuntu Kylin](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu-kylin)

Along with different features, i think a type of this in english but no features removed would be actually pretty good.